# Need to pass Bigquery Array of Struct parameter in Java

Tags: google-bigquery

I have requirements where i have to pass Array of struct as parameter and then join with main table. In different way, i have list of values of say column x and y that i have pass and then join column x of passed value to column x of main table but not able to do it. I have to pass the parameter using java code. My SQL Queries is something like below.

```
select i.x, 
  z.y,
  COUNT(*) AS countTotal

  from `table` i
  inner join UNNEST(ARRAY<STRUCT<x STRING, y STRING>>[('a1','b1'),('a2','b2'),('a3','b3')]) z ON i.x = z.x

WHERE ( z.y='b1' ) 
OR (z.y='b2') 
OR (z.y='b3') 

  group by i.x, z.y
  
  order by i.x;
```

I need to pass inner join portion as parameter in Java, basically below line

```
ARRAY<STRUCT<x STRING, y STRING>>[('a1','b1'),('a2','b2'),('a3','b3')]
```

Thanks
Raviranjan